# Extjs 4 Ext.getBody().mask() - Make this particular mask transparent

Tags: javascript, css, extjs, extjs4

I am trying to create an ExtJS 4 mask which is transparent with no loading message in only one place.

```
Ext.getBody().mask(); 
<do something.....>
Ext.getBody().unmask();
```

The above code gives a mask without any loading message but still the mask is visible. I want to make it transparent. I tried to add another cls to it something like:

```
Ext.getBody().mask(false, 'myMask');
CSS
.myMask { background-color: transparent; opacity: 0; }
```

But it didn't work. :(

Also tried **Ext.LoadMask** but the loading message box appears even when no message is set.

Please help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `myMask` class is applied to the loading message but not to the mask element.You need to use following css:

```
.x-mask {
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0); // for older browsers
opacity: 0;
background: transparent;
}
```

**EDIT:**

To do it for a paritcular case. We need to **add** a **class** to **body** & **remove** that **class** while **unmasking**.

```
Ext.getBody().addCls('transparentMask'); 
Ext.getBody().mask(); 
<do something.....>
Ext.getBody().unmask();
Ext.getBody().removeCls('transparentMask');
```

CSS:

```
.transparentMask .x-mask {
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0); // for older browsers
opacity: 0;
background: transparent;
}
```

Comment: But in this case all the masks in the application will get impacted. I want to do it only for a particular mask.